# Updating a trigger to add another field to be updated

Tags: apex, trigger

I am hoping someone can guide me.  I have created this trigger on a custom object called `Trident Contract`.  It pulled the agent name from the custom object `Agent` using the Agent Id.  Now I need to add the `Buyer Agent Office` to the trigger.  The `Buyer Agent` Lookup Field was working until I tried to also add the office.  Here is my first trigger.  Please advise how to add another field lookup.  Thank you

```
trigger BuyAgent on Trident_Contract__c (before insert, before update) {
    Set <String> AgentIDs = new Set <String>();
    for(Trident_Contract__c tc:trigger.new) {
        if(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c !=NULL){
            AgentIDs.add(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c);
        } 
    }
    //Match Agent ID to Buyer Agent ID
    //Map ID 

    Map<String, Agent__c> Agents = new map <String, Agent__C>();

    for (Agent__c obj: [
        SELECT ID, Agent_ID__c
        FROM Agent__c
        WHERE Agent_ID__c IN :AgentIDs]) {
        Agents.put(obj.Agent_ID__c,obj);
    }
    for(Trident_Contract__c tc : trigger.new) {
        if (Agents.containsKey(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c))
            tc.Buyer_Agent_Lookup__c = Agents.get(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c).ID;
    }
}
```

I updated the trigger to the following

```
trigger BuyAgent on Trident_Contract__c (before insert) {
    Set<String> lagid=new set<string>();
    for(Trident_Contract__c tc :Trigger.new){
        lagid.add(tc.buyer_agent_Id__c);
    }
    Map<String, String>matchid=new Map<String, String>();

    for(Agent__c ag: [
        SELECT Agent_ID__c, Agent_Office__c
        FROM Agent__c 
        WHERE Agent_ID__c IN :lagid]) {
        matchid.put(ag.Agent_ID__c, ag.Agent_Office__c);
    }
    for(Trident_Contract__c tc : Trigger.new) {
        if(matchid.containskey(tc.buyer_agent_ID__c))        
            tc.Buyer_Agent_lookup__c = matchid.get(tc.Buyer_Agent_Lookup__c);
            tc.Buyer_Agent_Office__c = matchid.get(tc.Buyer_Agent_Office__c);
        }
}
```

But it does not update the Buyer Office Field

Comment: What did you do to try to add office? It does not look like your code sample makes any reference to it.

Comment: Adrian, I have added the code but it does not work that is why I was asking how to update it

Answer (score 0):

The keys to your (updated trigger) map `matchId` are only values of `ag.agent_id__c` from the SOQL

As such, the line

```
tc.Buyer_Agent_Office__c = matchid.get(tc.Buyer_Agent_Office__c);
```

will never find any entries in `matchId` unless the `Buyer_agent_office__c` is the same as the `buyer_agent_id__c`

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code to the following and get an error message 'Line 1 Map must have exactly 2 arguments'

trigger BuyAgent on Trident_Contract__c (before insert, before update) {
Set  AgentIDs = new Set ();
    for(Trident_Contract__c tc:trigger.new){
        if(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c !=NULL){
            AgentIDs.add(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c,tc,Buyer_Agent_Office__C);
        } 
    }
    //Match Agent ID to Buyer Agent ID
    //Map ID

Map Agents = new map ();

```
for (Agent__c obj: [SELECT ID, Agent_ID__c
                    from Agent__c
                    Where Agent_ID__c 
                    IN: AgentIDs]){Agents.put(obj.Agent_ID__c,obj);}
```

for(Trident_Contract__c tc : trigger.new)
{if (Agents.containsKey(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c,tc.Buyer_Agent_Office__C))
                tc.Buyer_Agent_Lookup__c = Agents.get(tc.Buyer_Agent_ID__c).ID; 
 tc.Buyer_Agent_Office__c = matchid.get(tc.Buyer_Agent_Office__c);
  }
}